# How to convert a price list in PDF format to CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, csv

I receive multiple price lists from Fruit and Vegetable day traders in PDF format. I want to convert them to CSV and preform some basic price analytics/comparisons.

Take a look at two real examples of the pdf price lists **[here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/senter5rvr0nv48/FRUIT_PRICELIST.pdf)** and **[here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/n17jr5vpz9i8fav/FRUIT_2_PRICELIST.pdf)**.

What would you suggest I use to convert a PDF to CSV to do some basic analytics?

Comment: did you find some converter gem?

Answer (score -1):

This API can be called from any language or you can upload the PDF with the UI:
https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api

Convert to Excel, CSV, XML or HTML